# Cloud Task Location and Cloud Function Locations are Different

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-cloud-tasks

When I first set up my Cloud Tasks I never choose a location, I let Google do it based off of my project settings. When I run `$ gcloud functions list` all of my functions are in `us-central1`

[image]

When I go to the Cloud Task console to check on my queue the Location is `us-east1` and when I run `$ gcloud app describe` I get `locationId: us-east1`

[image]

**Why are the Locations different and will this cause any issues with my project?**

Im my index.js file I use the following to set my `queuePath`:

```
const project = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG!).projectId;
const location = 'us-east1';
const queue = 'ttl-task';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most (?) cases, Console or `gcloud` require the user to provide a location if it's required for a deployment. There may be exceptions; Firestore databases are colocated with App Engine apps and, App Engine apps once located in a project are singletons and can't be moved, for example.

`gcloud` has an accompanying `config` command that sets defaults for subsequent `gcloud` commands. This can catch the (un)wary and I recommend not setting defaults (beside the auth account) and always e.g. `--region=...` or `--location=...` etc when using `gcloud`; this is more clearly intentional particularly in scripts (although remains imperfect).

You likely either chose the Console default or had a `region` or `location` default set when you deployed the Cloud Tasks.

Generally, you want to minimize network traffic "distance" because it's always faster to send network traffic within one e.g. location than across locations because these are physically distant and even light would take non-zero time to transit the space.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question is **YES** this will definitely cause an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69474993/4833705). The function that's associated with the Cloud Task needs to be in the same region as the Cloud Task. It's a very easy fix though. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69474993/cloud-task-function-not-firing-any-resource-that-needs-app-engine-can-only-be-c/69476854#69476854)