# Cloud Task function not firing -Any resource that needs App Engine can only be created/updated in the App Engine region

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-cloud-tasks

My handler named *taskToFireOff* has `allUsers` deleted, the `Cloud Tasks Enqueuer` principal's name is set to the `ServiceAccountEmail`, and its role is set to `Invoker` (not shown)

[image]

When a post is created, I use `.onCreate` to create a task. **The task is created but the function that the http request is connected to never fires**. I looked here https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudtasks/queue/ and see that there are 2 tasks (I tried twice) just sitting there.

When I go to the Cloud Task page in the console > click the task > Tasks > `Method / URL`, it says

> POST https://us-east1-myProjectId.cloudfunctions.net/taskToFireOff

But when I go to the task > Logs > View > Suggested > Query Details it says

> New error group seen in onCreateData: Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Any
> resource that needs App Engine can only be created/updated in the App
> Engine region. Location must equal **us-east1** because the App

It's an odd error because the above url begins with **us-east1** and in my index.js file I set the location using us-east1

```
exports.onCreateData = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postId}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

    const payload = {"postId": context.params.postId};

    const project = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG!).projectId;
    const location = 'us-east1';
    const queue = 'ttl-task';
    const serviceAccountEmail = 'yaddayadda@myProjectId.iam.gserviceaccount.com';

    const queuePath = tasksClient.queuePath(project, location, queue);

    const url = `https://${location}-${project}.cloudfunctions.net/taskToFireOff`

    const task = {
        httpRequest: {
            httpMethod: 'POST',
            url,
            oidcToken: {
                serviceAccountEmail
            },
            body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString('base64'), // JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payloadData));
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        },
        scheduleTime: {
            seconds: // ...
        }
    }

    const [response] = await tasksClient.createTask({ parent: queuePath, task });

    // ...
});

exports.taskToFireOff = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    // ...
});
```

Also while inside the console, when I click the Task itself and look at the payload, all the correct information is there.

When I created my RealTimeDatabase I was given `us-central1`

[image]

But when I created my Storage bucket, I selected `us-east1`. At the bottom of Firestore Database it says

[image].

When I enter `$ gcloud app describe` it says that the locationId is `us-east1`

[image]

**Could the problem be that the Cloud Task is in `us-east1` but the Cloud Functions are in `us-central1`?**

Running `$ gcloud functions list` lists all of my Cloud Functions in the `us-central1` region

[image]

Btw, I created another project just to see the selection that I'm given when creating a Storage bucket. For Storage, there isn't a way to select us-central1. There is a default `Multi-region nam5(us-central`) but there isn't a specific region for `us-central1`. I selected `us-east1` because I'm in NY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the App Engine was in `us-east1` but the function handler *taskToFireOff* was in `us-central1`. The error was saying that the function associated with App Engine/Cloud Task needs to be in the same region together. In short I needed to change that particular cloud function’s region.

To fix the issue I had to create a new handler which was pretty easy. I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53528902/4833705) which led me to this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify-region) specifically the **Change a function's region or regions** section.

1st- in terminal I ran:

```
$ gcloud app describe 
// use whatever appears for the locationId which for me was us-east1
```

2nd- I added this new function to the index.js file:

```
// whatever appeared for the locationId I put inside the region param

exports.newTaskToFireOff = functions.region('us-east1').https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    // ... in here I c+p all of the code from my initial taskToFireOff function
});
```

3rd- I ran this in terminal to update gcloud with the new function

```
$ firebase deploy --only functions:newTaskToFireOff
```

4th- I ran this in terminal to delete the old function from gcloud:

```
$ firebase functions: delete taskToFireOff
```

5th- I went into my index.js file and manually deleted the entire *taskToFireOff*. You won't need the old function, just the code from inside of it

```
// I deleted this old function
exports.taskToFireOff = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    // ... I took this code and c+p inside the newTaskToFireOff before I deleted this function
});
```

7th-

When I go to the console's [Cloud Functions page](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/) the old *taskToFireOff* is no longer there and the *newTaskToFireOff* is there with the region `us-east1`

After you finish these steps don’t forget that the new function from step 2 you have to go to the Cloud console (use the above link) and change its `Permissions`. Set the role to `Invoker` and set its principal role name to use whatever you set for the Cloud Task's `ServiceAccountEmail` otherwise it still won’t work. You should delete `allUsers` too.