# Firebase Scheduled Functions Not Fully Deploying

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions

I have been trying to deploy the following function for days. This is the code and the errors. It appears on my google cloud platform but it is not working properly.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();

// prettier-ignore
exports.schFunc = functions.region("us-east1").pubsub
    .schedule("every 1 minutes")
    .onRun((context) => {
      database
          .doc("timers/timer1")
          .update({time: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()});
      return console.log("succesful timer update");
    });
```

These are the errors.

```
<<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Any resource that needs App Engine can only be created/updated in the App Engine region. Location must equal us-east1 because the App Engine app that is associated with this project is located in us-east1.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}
<<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY {"error":{"code":404,"message":"Job not found.","status":"NOT_FOUND"}}
```

And this is what is showing when I deploy.

```
Error: Failed to upsert schedule function schFunc in region us-east1


Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

Comment: Does this post answer your question? [Cloud Task function not firing -Any resource that needs App Engine can only be created/updated in the App Engine region](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69476854/16531380)